# How to draw an arrow between two div elements and keep it between them on window resize?

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

By messing with the x an y properties of this arrow I can line up my arrow to connect one div to another, but what I cannot figure out is how to make the arrow dynamically resize and always be connected to the same two divs even when I resize the window. Currently the arrow just stays fixed in place..
This is my svg:

```
<svg id="connectors" height="100%" width="100%">
    <defs>
        <marker id="markerArrow" markerWidth="13" markerHeight="13" refX="2" refY="6"
        orient="auto">
            <path d="M2,2 L2,11 L10,6 L2,2" />
        </marker>
    </defs>

<line x1="301" y1="550" x2="380" y2="350" class="arrow" />
</svg>
```

minimal example, as requested: https://codepen.io/ricodon1000/pen/dyYgbJe
(also below as a snippet)
The arrow should connect the two boxes at all times no matter how I resize the viewport.

```css
.main {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-item: space-around;
}
.main div {
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 10rem;
  width: 10rem;
}
.div1 {
  position: relative;
  top: 10rem;
}
.div2 {
  position: relative;
  top: 30rem;
}
svg{
position: absolute;
left: 0;
pointer-events: none;
}
.arrow {
  stroke: red;
  stroke-width: 2;
  marker-end: url(#markerArrow);
}
#markerArrow {
  fill: red;
}
#connectors {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="div1">
    <p>test</p>
  </div>
  <div class="div2">
    <p>test</p>
  </div>
  <svg id="connectors" height="100%" width="100%">
  <defs>
    <marker id="markerArrow" markerWidth="13" markerHeight="13" refX="2" refY="6" orient="auto">
      <path d="M2,2 L2,11 L10,6 L2,2" />
    </marker>
  </defs>

  <line x1="260" y1="315" x2="430" y2="500" class="arrow" />
</svg>
</div>
```

Comment: you need to add a viewbox in your svg

Comment: I would recommend to only use the SVG as the end of the arrow and use a pseudo element as the line that has a height or width based on the distance between the divs. Could you include the divs and make [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your situation.

Comment: @emielzuubier did that!

Comment: Note that the [mre] page linked to by @EmielZuurbier mentions that the example should be complete, part of which is that the code must be include *in the question itself*, not only on an external site. It also mentions [Stack Snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/215552) (the icon looks like `<>` on the editor toolbar), which provides a method for making HTML/CSS/JS code snippets that are runnable here on Stack Overflow.

Comment: @hereticmonkey okay, I did all that!

Comment: Ooh, yeah, the SVG has 100% height and width, so you'd have to write some crazy JavaScript to get that line to stay connected all the time... I'd put everything in SVG myself.

Comment: @hereticmonkey would you perhaps be willing to give me an example in the form of an answer? Because I am honestly quite lost and don't know where to start from.

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39575674/128511) connects divs with a line. As for being responsive you need to recompute the arrows in JavaScript on resize